# Sort the Array with Absolute value only and show real value

Tags: java

**print the absolute sorted array. See the sample output for clarification.**

**Input:**

```
9 -2 10 3 -5 34 -22 7
```

**I want output:**

```
-2 3 -5 7 9 10 -22 34
```

I was tried with `Arrays.sort(a[]);`

please help me out:

Thank you

Comment: `Math.abs()` might help you out.

Comment: k thank you.. how do i write logic @MuratK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Java 8, you can use lambda and Math.abs like this:

```
Integer[] array = {9,-2,10,3,-5,34,-22,7};
Arrays.sort(array, (a,b) -> (Integer.compare( Math.abs(a),  Math.abs(b))));
Stream.of(array).forEach(a ->  System.out.println(a));
```

Thanks to 4castle for suggestion. Or use Comparator

```
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs));
```

Comment: Instead of a lambda, you can use `Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs)`

Comment: @ShivaNandam Its used to convert arrays to stream, so you can make use of stream feature similar to list.

Comment: [It works for me](https://ideone.com/ZRoeeo). Instead of using a stream, that last line could just be a for..each loop, or `Arrays.asList(array).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs));` does not compile for me with DrJava. Gives an error *The method comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction<? super T>) in the type java.util.Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (Math::abs)*

Comment: what about if the arrays is of primitive type?

Answer (score 2):

A concise way to do it is

```
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs));
```

> **Example.**
>
> input: [9,-2,10,3,-5,34,-22,7]
>
> output: [-2, 3, -5, 7, 9, 10, -22, 34]
>
> ```
>     Integer[] array = {9,-2,10,3,-5,34,-22,7};
>
>     Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs));
>
>     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
> ```

Comment: I can run it here, maybe your input array are not integers but doubles or something?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what syntax is "Math::abs"? I haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` with an additional comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(a, new AbsComparator());
```

The comparator itself could look like this:

```
class AbsComparator extends Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return Math.abs(i1) < Math.abs(i2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparator is an Interface. Should we use implements here instead of extends?

Answer (score -1):

You can get the absolute value of numbers ,then you can do the sort

In Java

`double f = Math.abs(-2);` gives you value 2 Then you can perform Sorting.

Comment: ok thank you.. but after doing Math.abs(-2) i can't get the same output